# How to refresh data in datagridview from main form when I add record in second form using Vb.Net

Tags: vb.net, datagridview

I used refresh but not working. thanks for help

```
Private Sub frm_Add_Teacher_Closing(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.ComponentModel.CancelEventArgs) Handles MyBase.Closing
        frm_View_Teacher.Refresh()
End Sub
```

Comment: You can do that with a common Event placed in a Common Module.

Comment: There's nothing to refresh. The grid displays the data that is bound to it. If you don't change the data that's bound to it, why would anything in the grid change? If you expect to display data from a database in the grid then you have to actually get that data from the database. You obviously know how to do that if you have already populated the grid once. There's no magic involved. You just have to populate it again.

Comment: That said, like so many people, you're doing things the wrong way around. You shouldn't need to change the grid because it should already be changed, before the database. Instead of the other form saving data to the database, it should simply return data to the calling form, i.e. the one containing the grid. That form should then add that data to the `DataTable` that's already bound to the grid, thus updating the grid first, and then use a data adapter to save those changes from that `DataTable` to the database.

Comment: Thanks sir. I got the answer. Here is my code

Comment: Private Sub cmd_TAdd_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles cmd_TAdd.Click
        sql.ClearTextBox(Me) 'clear fields
        cmd_TUpdate.Enabled = False 'disable update button
        Dim frm As New frm_Add_Teacher 'call new 
        frm.ShowDialog()
        If frm.DialogResult = Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK Then
            load_Teacher()
        End If
        '    

    End Sub

Answer (score 0):

You're making it too complicated. Just share the data source between the forms

- Make a brand new project; a temporary one
- Paste this code in over the top of everyhting in the Form1.vb file:

```
Public Class Form1
    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        Dim dt As New DataTable()
        dt.Columns.Add("A")
        dt.Rows.Add("One")
        dt.Rows.Add("Two")

        Dim dgv As New DataGridView
        Me.Controls.Add(dgv) 'add dgv to this form
        dgv.DataSource = dt

        Dim f2 = New Form2(dt)
        f2.Show()

    End Sub
End Class

Public Class Form2
    Inherits Form
    Public Sub New(d As DataTable)
        Dim dgv2 As New DataGridView
        Me.Controls.Add(dgv2) 'add a dgv to this form too
        dgv2.DataSource = d
    End Sub
End Class
```

- Run the project

Have a play with the grids, adding and changing data. you'll see how the forms (one is behind the other) show the same data and you'll see how, as you edit that data in one, the other updates.

This is because they share the same model of data. One thing changes the model, the other sees it and updates